# Initialize Gensim LDA model with pre-determined priors

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I would like to create a LDA model (i.e. an instance of gensim.models.LdaModel) returning a pre-determined topic-word distribution. The reason for doing this is that I would like to leverage Gensim, pyLDAvis, etc to display the results on some topic-word distribution that I obtain from other algorithms.

Is that possible? Below I show some incomplete code (because I find the ML community intimidating):

```
import gensim
texts=[['a','a','b'], ['a','b','c'],['b','c','c']]
d = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(texts)
bow = [d.doc2bow(doc) for doc in texts]

my_topics=[[2/3, 1/3, 0],[0, 2/3, 1/3]]
model = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus=bow, id2word=d, num_topics=2, 
        eta=..., alpha..., passes=0, iterations=0, random_state=1)
model.show_topics(num_words=3)
# Hopefully return my_topics above
#[(0, '0.666*"a" + 0.333*"b"'),
# (1, '0.666*"b" + 0.333*"c"')]
```

I was hoping to achieve this by initializing eta in the LDA model and by setting iterations to 0. In my attempts (not shown) the resulting topics are not the same as 'my_topics'.

[Gensim docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel):

> eta ({float, np.array, str}, optional) –
>
> A-priori belief on word probability, this can be:
>
> ```
>     scalar for a symmetric prior over topic/word probability,
>     vector of length num_words to denote an asymmetric user defined probability for each word,
>     matrix of shape (num_topics, num_words) to assign a probability for each word-topic combination,
>     the string ‘auto’ to learn the asymmetric prior from the data.
> ```

EDIT: This (calling reset on the model's state) seems to work, but I am not sure it makes theoretically sense

```
model = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus=bow, id2word=d, num_topics=2, 
    eta=my_topics, alpha=1, passes=0, iterations=0, random_state=1)
model.state.reset()
model.show_topics(num_words=3)
#array([[0.6666667 , 0.33333334, 0.        ],
#   [0.        , 0.6666667 , 0.33333334]], dtype=float32)
```

However, the topic distribution for a given document is not trained and I do not think it can be keeping the topics constant:

```
model.get_document_topics(bow[2])
model[bow[2]]
#[(0, 0.55569696), (1, 0.44430298)]
```